# How to group similar rows based on values in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, set, grouping

I'm trying to group rows based on a set of values in different columns.

```
data = {'Loan': [100,100,100,200,200,200,201,201],'Collateral': ['COL-A', 'COL-B', 'COL-C', 'COL-A', 'COL-B','COL-C', 'COL-A', 'COL-B'], 'Pos':[1,1,2,1,1,2, 2, 2]}
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The expected result should be

```
GroupID Loan    Collateral  Pos
10  100 COL-A   1
10  100 COL-B   1
10  100 COL-C   2
10  200 COL-A   1
10  200 COL-B   1
10  200 COL-C   2
20  201 COL-A   2
20  201 COL-B   2
```

I've thought about different ways of doing it but could use some help.
GroupID can be anything, I just picked some random numbers a unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

One of options is to use a **grouping function**.

Such a function is called with the key of the current record, say *key*.
Then, assuming that index values are uniue, this function can:

- read the current row (`row = temp_df.loc[key]`),
- check values of fields of interest (`row.some_column`),
- return the grouping key based on some logic.

As you didn't specify your logic, I assume that the grouping key should be:

- if *Loan == 201 and Pos == 2* then *20*,
- otherwise *10*.

So the grouping function can be e.g.:

```
def grpFun(key):
    row = temp_df.loc[key]
    ln = row.Loan
    p = row.Pos
    return 20 if ln == 201 and p == 2 else 10
```

To group rows, run:

```
gr = temp_df.groupby(grpFun)
```

To see the result, run:

```
for key, grp in gr:
    print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{grp}')
```

and (for your data) you will see:

```
Group: 10
   Loan Collateral  Pos
0   100      COL-A    1
1   100      COL-B    1
2   100      COL-C    2
3   200      COL-A    1
4   200      COL-B    1
5   200      COL-C    2

Group: 20
   Loan Collateral  Pos
6   201      COL-A    2
7   201      COL-B    2
```

## Variant 2

If you want this grouping key to be saved as a **separate** column,
e.g. for future use, the approach should be a little different:

Define the grouping function as follows:

```
def grpFun2(row):
    ln = row.Loan
    p = row.Pos
    return 20 if ln == 201 and p == 2 else 10
```

Apply it to each row, saving the result in a new column:

```
temp_df.insert(0, 'GroupID', temp_df.apply(grpFun2, axis=1))
```

## Edit following your comment

If you want to have each group with the same values in *Collateral* and *Position*
then just *groupby* on these 2 columns:

```
temp_df.groupby(['Collateral', 'Position'])
```

and then do with each group whatever you want.

A downside (in my opinion not very significant) is that the grouping key is
now a **tuple** (actually a pair), composed of these 2 columns.

But note that now your grouping will be different from your expected result:

```
Group (COL-A, 1):
100 COL-A   1
200 COL-A   1

Group (COL-A, 2):
201 COL-A   2

Group (COL-B, 1):
100 COL-B   1
200 COL-B   1

Group (COL-B, 2):
201 COL-B   2

Group (COL-C, 2):
100 COL-C   2
200 COL-C   2
```

Comment: The goal is to essentially find sets of groups that have the same values in collateral and position. Hard coding in the grouping key is not viable on a larger data set. Ideally it was be an autoincrementing integer.